# Slick carousel responsive breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

This is the configuration I am using to create a slick carousel on my web page:

```
$('#carousel').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1200,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 1008,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 800,
      settings: 'unslick',
    },
  ],
})
```

It is working the way it is supposed to work except for one thing... when I resize my browser window from `width: 1920` to `800`, the carousel unslicks it, and the content is displayed like normal divs.

But then when I increase the `width` of the browser window the carousel doesn't recreate it. It remains like HTML `div` blocks without carousel.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

unslick is a destructor method. Once you unslick, you need to call slick() again to construct carousel.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you show me how you've fixed it?

Answer (score 9):

This is one way to rebuild the carousel after unslick kills it at a breakpoint:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.js-slider').not('.slick-initialized').slick('resize');
});

$(window).on('orientationchange', function () {
    $('.js-slider').not('.slick-initialized').slick('resize');
});
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<section class="regular slider" style="direction:ltr">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=7">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=8">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=9">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=10">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=11">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=12">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=13">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=14">
    </div>
</section>
```

***/////script/////***

```
    $(document).on('ready', function() {

      $(".regular").slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 6,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,

          pauseOnHover: true,

        responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 5,
                slidesToScroll: 5,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 3
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 2
            }
        }

  ]


      }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

On each browser resize event you need to do a check and reinitialize the Slick slider if needed (if you are on mobile and Slick slider is not initialized).

```
/* Get element */
var slider = $('.slider');
 
/* Slider settings */
var settings = {...}
 
/* Do this every time window gets resized */
$(window).on('resize', function() {
 
   /* If we are above mobile breakpoint unslick the slider */
   if ($(window).width() >= 800) 
   {
      /* Do this only if slider is initialized */
      if (slider.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
         slider.slick('unslick');
      }
      return;
   }
   /* We are below mobile breakpoint, initialize the slider
      if it is not already initialized */
   else if (!slider.hasClass('slick-initialized')) 
   {
      return slider.slick(settings);
   }
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: You would not actually need the responsive:[...] part if all you need it for is the unslick whilst you call unslick within your own resize-handler. correct?

Comment: Well you needed that part for initial slider initialization, but I agree it could have been written better. I edited my response - dropped the responsive setting, removed initial slider call and triggered the 'resize' event on window.

Comment: What a mess, but that's not your fault

Answer (score 2):

I solved the responsive breakpoint issue, recalculating the number of slides at any browser resize.
**.testimonialsList**: it's the name of the container of my carousel.

```
// Create carousel
function createTestimonialCarousel(numberOfSlides){
    jQuery('.testimonialsList').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
        dots: true,
        arrows: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: numberOfSlides,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 6000,
        pauseOnHover: true
    });
}

// Calculate number of slides to show
function calculateNumberOfSlidesToShow(){
    var carouselWidth = jQuery(".testimonialsList").width();
    var numberOfSlides = 0;
    switch (true) {
        case (carouselWidth < 767):
            numberOfSlides = 1;
            break;
        case (carouselWidth < 991):
            numberOfSlides = 2;
            break;
        case (carouselWidth < 1199):
            numberOfSlides = 3;
            break;
        case (carouselWidth > 1200):
            numberOfSlides = 3;
            break;
    }

    return numberOfSlides;
}

// Reload Carousel on browser resize (to make it responsible)
function reloadCarousel () {
    jQuery('.testimonialsList').slick('unslick');
    numberOfSlides = calculateNumberOfSlidesToShow();
    createTestimonialCarousel(numberOfSlides);
}

// Call updateMaxHeight when browser resize event fires
jQuery(window).on("resize", reloadCarousel);



jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // Initialize the carousel on page load
    if (jQuery(".testimonialsList").length) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            numberOfSlides = calculateNumberOfSlidesToShow();
            createTestimonialCarousel(numberOfSlides);
        }, 300);
    }


});
```